# react-table tbody is not vertically scrollable

Tags: css, reactjs, html-table, react-table

I'm using react-table along with styled components and trying to make a tbody scrollable with sticky thead. I've tried to set a height to a parent container and then set tbody overflow-y to auto, however this approach doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-pond-yg9fj?file=/src/App.js)

```
const TableContainerOuter = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  padding-bottom: 21px;
`;

const TableContainer = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  min-width: 900px;
`;

const StyledTable = styled.table`
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  height: 30px;
  border-spacing: 0px;

  th {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #f3f4f5;
    font-size: 9px;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 230%;
    letter-spacing: 0.05em;
    color: ${(props) => props.theme.pbDarker};
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 6px 0px;
    user-select: none;
    &:first-child {
      border-top-left-radius: 6px;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
      padding-left: 22px;
    }
    &:last-child {
      border-top-right-radius: 6px;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
    }
  }

  tbody {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 100px;
  }

  td {
    padding: 16px 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 400;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-color: ${(props) => props.theme.pbFaded1};
    min-width: 95px;
    :first-of-type {
      padding-left: 22px;
    }
  }
`;
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not applying overflow. You can see if you inspect your table. Add overflow to your TableContainer and it will work. See down below

```
const TableContainer = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  min-width: 900px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
`;
```

Comment: Thank you. But what I wanted to achieve is that the scroll bar sits below header so only body is scrollable otherwise it looks like the whole table is scrollable.

Comment: @AlinaKhachatrian You can't really do that. You could set tbody to display: block. However, you'll lose th and td fixed width because browser won't see it anymore as the table, but you'll have scroll on it.

Comment: Yes I've tried that too but I have to follow the designs so it has to be below header ...

Comment: @AlinaKhachatrian you can set a fixed width on the table and space out elements in tr according to it. Also you could write some js to set the width according to screen size to make it more dynamic

Answer (score 0):

Create 2 tables. One with the column headings one without any. Set the second table to scroll

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30510988)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with such solution

```
tbody {
    height: calc(100vh - 310px); // Your prefered height here
    table-layout: fixed;
    display: block;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }

  thead, tbody tr {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
  }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).